# How to create an op like conv_ops in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm new to C++ and bazel and I want to make some change on the convolution operation in tensorflow, so I decide that my first step is to create an ops just like it.

**What I have done**

I copied conv_ops.cc from //tensorflow/core/kernels and change the name of the ops registrated in my new_conv_ops.cc. I also changed some name of the functions in the file to avoid duplication. And here is my BUILD [file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKxAc.png)

As you can see, I copy the deps attributes of conv_ops from //tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD. Then I use "bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:new_conv_ops.so" to build the new op.

**What my problem is**

Then I got this [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tWFo.png)

I tried to delete bounds_check and got same error for the next deps. Then I realize that there is some problem for including h files in //tensorflow/core/kernels from //tensorflow/core/user_ops. So how can I perfectely create a new op excatcly like conv_ops?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom operation to TensorFlow is covered in the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html). You can also look at actual code [examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/adding_an_op).

To address your specific problem, note that the `tf_custom_op_library` macro adds most of the necessary dependencies to your target. You can simply write the following :

```
tf_custom_op_library(
  name="new_conv_ops.so",
  srcs=["new_conv_ops.cc"]
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! However it's true that if the BUILD file is simply writen like above, there will be a error say "this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by" and the files I include in my BUILD file are mentioned. I have done some search online and found the cc_library definition of user_ops_op_lib in the BUILD file of //tensorflow/core. I added the files needed in the deps attribute of the library but it didn't work. So I think maybe I should define the dependency right in the BUILD of my .so file.

Comment: I have also read the actual code examples you mentioned above, but they are not involved in any dependency of h files in //tensorflow/core/kernels and etc. So I wonder if there is any more complex examples(ops that include not just op.h and op_kernel.h)

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue while adding a new op. Were you able to resolve this issue? I would be glad to get help on this.